# Salesforce SOQL REST Query with empty fields

Tags: salesforce

If I make an SOQL query such as:

select Id, Username, UserRoleId from User

The API correctly returns the results as XML, however because none of the rows contain a UserRoleId entry this node is completely excluded from the results.

Ideally I would like to be able to create a table from the resultant XML showing all the requested columns, even if they are empty. Is there a way of forcing the API to return even empty columns so that I can do this without resorting to something messy like parsing the SOQL query?

Comment: I dont think that is possible. Why do you run into situation of parsing the SOQL query anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a better idea to when you receive an result. Check if the curtain column row is empty. When the column is empty, than you know you have set a empty column by yourself. It is just an idea of my.

Think about a try catch, just an example I use in my application:

```
try {
    parentId = records.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Parent).getString("Name");
catch (JSONException e) {
    parentId = "a";
}
```

When the column name from Parent is empty, then parentId = a. I'd set it manually because I know some other data rolls could have that data.